# How can i refresh buttons inside a cell in CollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Given that:
For example in a collectionView there are 8 cells & each cell has a button & an image.Buttons here will display Yes/No Option to the user. Out of 8 cells only 1 cell will show "Yes" and remaining cells should show "No".

What i am looking is?
When i tap on a different button then current button show display "Yes" and previous button display "No".

I don't want to reload entire collectionView or cells inside a section in collectionView.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of reloadItemsAtIndexPaths method of collection View to reload multiple cells(In your case 2 cell i.e the minimum number of cells to be reloaded) instead of reloading whole collectionView.Pass the indexpath of the cell that you want to reload 
ex:

```
  //Logic to change button title Yes to No comes here.
  collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath1, indexPath2])
```

indexPath1, indexPath2 are the index paths to be reloaded.

Comment: how can i refresh only buttons in  cell?

Comment: @Audi You need not to refresh the button you just have to get the reference to the button and set it's title.